# Create a specific macro with typeof in C

Tags: c, gcc

To simplify the question, if I have two structs like the following:

```
typedef struct test1_s {
    uint16_t value1;
    uint16_t b;
} test1_t;

typedef struct test2_s {
    uint32_t value1;
    uint32_t c;
} test2_t;
```

And I want a macro to work like this:

```
value = GET(x, value1);
```

but for different type of x, different process will be done for x->value1.

What I'm thinking of is that:

```
#define GET_test1_t_value1(x) x->value1 + 1
#define GET_test2_t_value1(x) x->value1 + 2
#define GET(x, field) GET_##typeof(x)##_##field(x)
```

But looks like the typeof can not work like this....

Is there any way to achieve that? It needs to be done in pure C. Thanks!

Comment: `typeof` is evaluated by the compiler, not the preprocessor, so no, it's not possible.

Comment: I think so... I don't really need to use typeof though.... Any other solution? It is actually a question about how to achieve function overloading in pure C...

Comment: `typeof` is non-standard, and it doesn't expand to a string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` is non-standard (it's an extension provided by gcc, and perhaps by some other compilers). And it doesn't expand to a string, so as you've already discovered you can't use in a macro definition like the one you're trying to do.

C11 added a new `_Generic` keyword that permits something like what you want.  It's used in a new kind of expression called a *generic selection*.

An example from the C standard:

```
#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), \
                        long double: cbrtl, \
                        default: cbrt, \
                        float: cbrtf \
                        )(X)
```

(The `default` association permits the use of `cbrt` for integer types, which will be implicitly converted to `double`.)

See section 6.5.1.1 of the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the 2011 ISO C standard.

Of course you can use this only if your compiler supports it.  gcc first added support for `_Generic` in release 4.9, which came out just a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

,sample in C11

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct test1_s {
    uint16_t value1;
    uint16_t b;
} test1_t;

typedef struct test2_s {
    uint32_t value1;
    uint32_t c;
} test2_t;


#define GET(x, field) (x->field + _Generic(*x, test1_t: 1, test2_t:2))

int main(){
    uint32_t value;
    test1_t *x = &(test1_t){1,2};
    test2_t *y = &(test2_t){3,4};

    value = GET(x, value1);
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", value);//2
    value = GET(y, value1);
    printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", value);//5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get illegal expression `test1_t *x = &(test1_t)>>{<<1,2};` with c99 compiler.  C99 same as C11, no?

Comment: @ryyker: No, C99 is not the same as C11; in particular, C99 does not have `_Generic`. But even in C99 you shouldn't have gotten an error at that point. The error message implies that your compiler doesn't support *compound literals*, a feature supported in both C99 and C11, but not in C90. What compiler are you using, and with what options?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Lol, I think I mis-interpreted this ***[Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29)***.  I am using LabWindows/CVI with C99 extensions turned on. Thanks.

Comment: That's a pretty cool feature! Thanks! But when can this be applied into the industry....